# what snake is that in northern italy

Tags: species-identification, snake

[image: head]
[image: head+neck]
[image: body]
[image: climbing]

About 75 cm long. Thin tail. Camping site near Grado, Italy, northern Adriatic sea.
It climbed a tree in the rough bark and i followed it to take these photos.

Comment: It might be a better idea to embed the images in your question instead of just putting their links.

Comment: Excellent quality photos and good views of important parts for identification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a [whip snake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierophis), either a [Balkan whip snake](http://www.herpetology.eu/indexjs.htm?SpeciesPages/HieroGemon.htm) or a [green whip snake](http://www.herpetology.eu/indexjs.htm?SpeciesPages/HieroVirid.htm). They are both present in the very north of Italy, close to Slovenia. They both vary in color, but the coloration of this one seems to be more similar to the Balkan whip snake.

[image: balkan whip snake 1]

[image]
See also this [discussion](http://fieldherping.eu/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=878).

Comment: Thanks. I first compared it with natrix natrix, but the pattern didn't really match. There are also many small lizards on the camping ground, a common prey of whip snakes. My snake made jerky movements with its head when it was in the low bushes on the ground, I didn't see that in the videos. I'll accept your answer, but I'm open for other suggestions (or confirmations).